# Google Business profile: Provides service at one location and mobile service to several zip-codes

Tags: local-seo, google-my-business

My business provides service at a physical location and we can send a crew out to provide service in several zip-codes.

My objective is to show up in the Google Search Local Pack as well as on Google Maps in appropriate service areas.

Google Business profile creation forces selection of service business or storefront. My business is a hybrid of those. I prefer to avoid Google Ads to achieve the objective.

Can this be done, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides an option to include a service area for hybrid businesses.

> **Hybrid business:** A business that serves customers at their business address, but also directly visits or delivers to customers. If your business doesn’t have permanent on-site signage, it's not eligible as a storefront and should be listed as a service-area business.

There's instructions on how to activate this under the [manage service areas of your business](https://support.google.com/business/answer/9157481?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-or-edit-a-service-area:%7E:text=Manage%20service%20areas%20for%20your%20business) section.